# Convert date in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I created an scheduler application with  SQL server  and now i want to make another one using SQLite. I have a convert query in SQL and it does not work in SQLite. Can anyone help?

```
try
        {
            ObservableCollection<Classes.EventClass> listEvents = new ObservableCollection<EventClass>();

            SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=Scheduler.db;Version=3;"); 

            string query= "Select * from Sche_Event where CONVERT(DATE,Event_TimeFrom) = CONVERT(DATE,'"  +d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "') ORDER BY Event_TimeFrom ASC";


            SQLiteCommand command= new SQLiteCommand(query, conn); 

            conn.Open();
            SQLiteDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            { 
                EventClass dog = new EventClass();

                dog.DogID = dr.GetInt32(0);
                dog.DogName = dr.GetString(1);
                dog.DogText = dr.GetString(2);
                dog.DogPriority = dr.GetInt32(3);
                dog.DogTimeFrom = dr.GetDateTime(4);
                dog.DogTimeTo = dr.GetDateTime(5);
                dog.KliID = dr.GetInt32(6);

                listEvents .Add(dog);
            }
            return listEvents ;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

I expect that my code goes to While() and read the information about the Event but all it does it goes to Catch() and returns nothing.

The query in SQL works just fine but i dont not work with SQLite :(

Answer (score 0):

Of course the statement doesn't work in SQLite, because `convert()` is not a known function there. But if you're lucky you don't even need it, depending on the format in which the timestamp is stored in your SQLite table. As you didn't provide any sample data nor described what you [actually want to do](http://xyproblem.info), you could either read the [SQLite doc about date and time functions](http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) or rephrase your question to "How do I do X in SQLite?".